# having problems writing to/ creating a file C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm making a program that takes input and prints it to a text file and gives it the name of the date it was created, kind of like a digital journal. However when f5 in VS it starts with no errors, runs through as if all is well then when i check to see if it has created the file its nowhere to be found in the projects folder. thanks in advance for the help.

```
        string date;
        time_t now;
        struct tm nowlocal;
        now = time(NULL);
        nowlocal = *localtime(&now); 
        int year = nowlocal.tm_year + 1970; 
        date = to_string(nowlocal.tm_mday) + ":" + to_string(nowlocal.tm_mon) + ":" + to_string(year) + ".txt";
        char write[900];
        ofstream file;
        file.open(date);
        cout << "input text to write to the journal(900chars max):";
        cin >> write;
        file << write << endl;
        file.close();
```

Comment: AFAIK the ':' character is not allowed in file name under Windows - try to use a different separator, for example '-'.

Comment: You're trying to do a lot of things in this code. Try doing *fewer* of them, and see if it still fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main problem was your naming convention. `:` is not allowed in file names so your file was not being created. There were some other errors. Also you need to mess with your char array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string date;
    time_t now;
    struct tm nowlocal;
    now = time(NULL);
    nowlocal = *localtime(&now);
    int year = nowlocal.tm_year + 1970;
    date = to_string(nowlocal.tm_mday) + "_" + to_string(nowlocal.tm_mon) + "_" + to_string(year) + ".txt";  //changed all ':' to '_'
    //char write[900];
    string write;
    cout << date << endl;
    ofstream file(date);
    //file.open(date);          //this was also causing an error
                                //your file is already open 
    cout << "input text to write to the journal(900chars max): ";

    getline(cin, write);
    //cin >> write;

    file << write << endl;
    file.close();




    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I fixed some of the errors. It seems to be working now. I had to use a string instead of the array you were using. Did this in class so you can expect some errors in my code haha. Hopefully this helped! Good luck!